# Is it possible to create the app first before the website that will sync with it?

Tags: iphone, mobile, web

I currently have a developer creating a website for my project.  The plan was that we'll create the website and then we'll do the ios and android apps that will sync with the website, but the website has missed 2 deadlines so far and now need to wait another month according to my developer.  My question is, would it matter if I get a developer to start the mobile apps before this developer finally finishes the website?

Comment: Assuming you're using JSON endpoints in your web app, why not create a static JSON test document for your mobile app? Or you could respond with pre-determined JSON documents depending on parameters, one for each test scenario. Would take 10 minutes to set up in PHP (and probably many other server-side languages).

Comment: ummm, you lost me after the first word, hehe.  Seriously though guys, I'm just over having to wait for the site to be finished.  If anyone interested I could give them the link to see how much he's done in 3 months

Comment: OK, well if the developer is any good, they will understand that faked API endpoints are trivial to set up (assuming the website itself is being set up as an API). As to developer productivity, it is hard to determine whether they are any good - it depends on a lot of things, such as their technical skill level, their time management, their ability to maintain focus, whether your organisation's culture is keeping them happy, the quality of the specs, the availability of uninterrupted working time, the quality of project management... etc!

Answer (score 0):

Depends largely on how much integration you require with your website. You could probably start on the design of the mobile apps but the actual integration with databases, backend, certain apis, etc you will need to have your website ready.

Basically anything that the mobile app does that requires your main website will have to wait until that other developer is done sounds like.

Of course tho every case is different.

Comment: Thanks mate, I thought as much

Comment: @John Yeah no problem. Forgot to mention this but welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to accept the best answer on your question haha jk. Glad I could help tho!! :)